# Ruby on Rails: How do I implement shortcut keys in my webapp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've heard about javascript solutions, and accessorkeys...

Don't know either... but there seem to be mixed feelings about which to use.

I want standard key shortcuts for each OS (command for mac, ctrl for everything else)

any help / links / tutorials would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [js-hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/).

> jQuery.Hotkeys plugin lets you easily add and remove handlers for
>   keyboard events anywhere in your code
>   supporting almost any key combination.
>   It takes one line of code to
>   bind/unbind a hot key combination.

**Binding 'Ctrl+c'**

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+c', fn);
```